# Virtual machine prompts me for windows authentication credentials every time I maximize and restore it

Tags: windows-xp, virtual-machine, microsoft-virtual-pc

Can I set it to stop doing that? I have to connect to the domain of my company network, so it gets really annoying having to enter the password every time.

windows xp is being run and the main machine is win7

Comment: Confused.  Which system is prompting for authentication - the host or the guest?  I'm guessing the host?

Answer (score 0):

It will be the guest that is asking for authentication.

I get this running the VirtualXP machine to run legacy apps. I did solve it briefly by getting TweakUI and setting it to autologin but since my password changed it now doesn't work, despite me changing the autologin password to match the new one.